# Problem using Java's Math functions to come up with a page number for view pagination

Tags: java, math, pagination

If I have 2 database records and 25 records per page, then the following code:

```
System.out.println("page count: " + (double)2/25);
```

results in this output:

```
page count: 0.08
```

But because I am using this figure for pagination, I need the next highest integer, in this case: 1.

Both `Math.ceil` and `Math.abs` produce the result `0` or `0.0`.

How do I end up with a page number integer?

Comment: It sounds like the error is in code you're not showing us.

Comment: Why do you say that? Is there something wrong with what I have written above? Could you explain what you mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct way to do that is:

```
int pages = (totalRecords+recordsPerPage-1)/recordPerPage;
```

In your case: pages = (2 + 25 - 1)/25 = 26/25 = 1

Comment: +1: I can tell I'm used to dealing with PHP and the like... I thought about int / int equaling an int as to why `Math.ceil` wasn't working properly, but not for producing the correct result without using `ceil`/`floor`.

Answer (score 5):

`Math.ceil` should never give you `0` for `0.08`.  Clearly there's a bug in the code you didn't post.

```
System.out.println(Math.ceil((double)2/25));
```

outputs `1.0` in Java 6u21 just like you would expect.

At a guess, your other code is missing the cast to `double` on one of the arguments, and `int / int` always returns `int` in Java.

```
System.out.println(Math.ceil(2/25));
```

prints `0.0`.

Comment: I was doing: Math.ceil((2/25))

Comment: @Linc: You need to cast `2` or `25` to a double first, or you get int `0` before doing `Math.ceil`.  I've edited my answer to note that.

Comment: @Linc Math.ceil((double)2/25) . I am sure this will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can add 1 to your result and then do a cast to int.

```
(int) (1 + (double)2/25)
```

This will go to the next higher number and then truncate.

But, the correct equation would be:

```
(int) (0.5 + (double) 2/25)
```

So, if you have 25 then it would be:

```
0.5 + 25/25
```

or

```
0.5 + 1 so int of that is 1
```

You can round up by adding .5 and taking the int.

Comment: This is wrong, imagine if there is 25 records, with pageSize=25. The formula gives 2 pages, even though there is only 1 page.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get `0.08`, add `0.5` then do `Math.floor`.

Comment: @Linc: you ALWAYS add 0.5 before using floor.  Or, you could use Math.round which works like this: (int)Math.floor(a + 0.5f)